# Child component is rerendering despite using useMemo,

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have code like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (number) => {
    console.log("typeof", typeof number);
    items.includes(number)
      ? setItems((prevState) =>
          prevState.filter((prevSlot) => prevSlot != number)
        )
      : setItems((items) => [...items, number]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("items", items);
  }, [items]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ButtonDiv handleClick={handleClick} slot="5" />
      <ButtonDiv handleClick={handleClick} slot="10" />
      <ButtonDiv handleClick={handleClick} slot="15" />
      <ButtonDiv handleClick={handleClick} slot="20" />
      <ButtonDiv handleClick={handleClick} slot="25" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**ButtonDiv**

```
const ButtonDiv = ({ handleClick, slot }) => {
  return useMemo(() => {
    console.log("renderButton");
    return <button onClick={() => handleClick(slot)}>Click me</button>;
  }, [handleClick, slot]);
};
```

Here, on clicking on button div, it is re-rendering for every button components, how could I prevent it from happening, and still keep maintaining the core functionality of toggling value when clicked on button.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-state-forked-0bv8fp)

Answer (score 0):

Every time `App` renders, it generates a new `handleClick` function and passes it as a prop to `<ButtonDiv>`.

The `useMemo` hook lists `handleClick` in the dependencies.

Since `handleClick` has changed, the memoized function has to be called to regenerate the result.

---

You probably want to wrap the creation of `handleClick` in `useCallback`.

Comment: could you please share the sandbox link, I can't get it working. what should I place as dependency

Comment: Didn't work using callback as well,  here is the code. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-state-forked-0bv8fp?file=/src/App.js, on this scenario, if you click again and again same button, same number keeps adding, which should not happen

Comment: @AayushDahal — So if you click the button `5` multiple times it adds `5` multiple times? That is what the code you wrote does. You were asking about stopping the re-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a new reference of `handleClick`  every time that you are rendering the **App**

With some modifications and using `useCallback` you can make it work without re-rendering the divButtons, `useCallback` without deps will generate always the same instance so it won't be refreshing your buttons.

Had to remove the items state, since if you add it you will have always the instance of the state at the moment the handleClick is created, so using just the set state and the prevState we can manage to make it work

```
  const handleClick = useCallback(
    (number) => {
      console.log("typeof", typeof number, number);
        setItems((prevState) =>
            prevState.includes(number) ? 
              prevState.filter((prevSlot) => prevSlot != number) :
              [...prevState, number]
          )
    },
    []
  );
```

Adding image of working example.

[image]

Comment: I have tried this as well, but with this approach, I could no longer toggle value on `items`, could you please shrare the code sandbox link

Comment: Just added an image with the code that I have changed and the console showing that the toggling is working properly.

Comment: Didn't work, here is the code. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-state-forked-0bv8fp?file=/src/App.js, on this scenario, if you click again and again same button, same number keeps adding, which should not happen

Comment: That is because you are using the items, inside the handleClick function, since you are using useCallback the items are going to be the items that at the moment the snapshot of the function (probably empty []) if you review my code, I just use the setItems and make the validation using the prevState. Please review and check if it works